# Error codes returned by urllib/urllib2 and the actual page

Tags: python, error-handling

the normal behavior of urllib/urllib2 is if an error code is sent in the header of the response (i.e 404) an Exception is raised.

How do you look for specific errors i.e (40x, or 50x) based on the different errors, do different things. Also, how do you read the actual data being returned HTML/JSON etc (The data usually has error details which is different to the HTML error code)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

urllib2 raises a [`HTTPError`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError) when HTTP errors happen. You can get to the response code using `code` on the exception object. You can get the response data using `read()`:

```
>>> req = urllib2.Request('http://www.python.org/fish.html')
>>> try:
>>>     urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
>>>     print e.code
>>>     print e.read()
>>>
404
<actual data response will be here>
```

Comment: Dominic, the acutal data is not returned, i have updated the question with the exception code.

Comment: This will fail in a lot of cases since `URLError` doesn't have `code` attribute and `read()` method itself, but only its subclass `HTTPError` has.

Comment: @Issy - really? It works for me. What's not working about it? Your second comment suggested it was working! If mine's not working and @Denis' is then you should accept his answer instead.

Comment: In fact it works since HTTPError is subclass of URLError, so catching URLError will catch HTTPError too. But it contained a hidden error which might break in some other cases.

Answer (score 1):

In `urllib2` `HTTPError` exception is also a valid HTTP response, so you can treat an HTTP error as an exceptional event or valid response. But in `urllib` you have to subclass URLopener and define `http_error_<code>` method[s] or redefine `http_error_default` to handle them all.