# Urllib - HTTP 403 error with no message (Facebook notification)

Tags: python, facebook, urllib2, urllib, http-status-code-403

I have successfully used the following Python code, running on a Google App Engine server on localhost, to send Facebook notifications to myself.  I use the [template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/#templating) feature of Facebook notifications to expand a Facebook user ID into a bolded name in the text of the notification:

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+myOwnID+'/notifications'

values = {'access_token' : 426547656256546|4fhe34FJdeV3WvfF6SNfehs7GfW
                  'href' : 'http://localhost:8080/', 
              'template' : '@['+myOwnID+'] says hi.'}

req = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(values))
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Note that the app access token is made-up, but has the same format as a real token.

When I change the template's ID to the ID of one of my friends:

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+myOwnID+'/notifications'

values = {'access_token' : 426547656256546|4fhe34FJdeV3WvfF6SNfehs7GfW
                  'href' : 'http://localhost:8080/', 
              'template' : '@['+myFriendID+'] says hi.'}

req = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(values))
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

I get the error

```
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

It works the same even if I hard-code the IDs into the template, so it's not an issue of incorrect variable values.

Why does the second case not work?  How can I fix it?

Comment: And what's the text of the error response? knowing the HTTP error code isn't enough

Comment: @Igy Thanks for the suggestion - I wasn't aware that I could get more than just the error code, since I'm new to web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize that urllib2 can print a more detailed error message than just the status code, by replacing the last line with:

```
try:
    urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
    logging.info(error.read()) # or "print error.read()"
```

This gives the clear error message:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Cannot tag users who have not installed the app","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

For a fuller discussion of urllib2's behaviour with 403 status codes, see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233687/overriding-urllib2-httperror-and-reading-response-html-anyway), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803741/error-codes-returned-by-urllib-urllib2-and-the-actual-page) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482028/why-i-get-urllib2-httperror-with-urllib2-and-no-errors-with-urllib?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

It appears, according to your error message, that your friend has to install your app in order for you to send them notifications. There's nothing you can do to fix that.